# Manipulating percentage - cancel keeps changes

Tags: java, javascript, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm working with Spring-MVC & JSP, and everything works fine except for my Cancel button.  I have a controller containing /edit and /save.  Going into /edit, the percent value must render in (0 >= x >= 100) value.  Upon saving, we must save as percentage (0 >= x >= 1.0).  In the edit form, if you change the percentage value and hit cancel, then change will not take but the value will be *100 from what it was before.  For example, if you have 15% on the form, and under edit you change to 17.5 then hit cancel, the value will become 1500 instead of 15.

The value is obviously getting *100, but never reverts back during cancel.  I've placed the /100 line before isCancelled(request), but that makes the number incorrectly update to what was cancelled.  In the above example, 0.175 would save.  The save goes through hibernate and into the database, although we never get to save(modelBean).

Is there a proper way to manipulate numbers on the view, but not committing the change to the database?  I'd like to make the changes in the back-end to avoid user shenanigans.

Please let me know if I can provide any further info/detail.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit")
public String edit(@ModelAttribute("activeForm") SomeForm form, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long id) {
    MyBean bean = getBeanById(id);

    // Converts % to user friendly xx.xx.
    if (form.getPercentage() != null) {
        double per = form.getPercentage() * 100.0d;
        form.setPercentage(per);
        bean.setPercentage(per);
    }
    return someString;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save")
public String save(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("activeForm") SomeForm form) {

    if (isCancelled(request)) {
        return REDIRECT_SUMMARY;
    }

    MyBean modelBean= getModel(form);

    // Converts user friendly xx.xx to %.
    if (form.getPercentage() != null) {
        double per = form.getPercentage() / 100.0d;
        form.setPercentage(per);
        modelBean.setPercentage(per);
    }
    save(modelBean);
    return someString;
}

public class SomeForm {
    private Double m_percentage = 1.0d;
    private Long m_id;

    // getters & setters here
}

<form:from action="/save" method="POST" modelAttribute="activeForm">
    <td><form:input path="valuationPercentage" maxlength="6"  />%</td>
    <jsp:include page="/lib/buttons.jsp" />
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By any chance do you have Hibernate session opened in your view? For example using [`OpenSessionInViewInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html)? If that would be the case and assuming that `MyBean` in your edit controller method is a managed JPA entity, the changes would be persisted, because you're setting the percentage to both your bean and form object:

```
form.setPercentage(per);
bean.setPercentage(per);
```

If that is the case I would just remove the `setPercentage` call on your bean and leave it on the form only.

By the way: I don't understand why are you using `isCancelled(request)`. If you want to cancel the edits, just implement the cancel button as link going to the URL represented by `REDIRECT_SUMMARY`. At least that's how I do it.

Comment: Thanks Bohuslav!  Removing bean.setPercentage() did the trick.  I believe I had looked at this code a bit too long the other day :)  This is just a snippet from a much, much larger enterprise system that has a lot going on in the background.  Hibernate was on point with bean update, despite not intentionally saving.  As for REDIRECT_SUMMARY, we have many urls that could be redirected to, depending on where you are.  This was made generic for the app.  Thanks again!